# QT setting text of lineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to learn QT and wanted to set the text of a `lineEdit` when pressing a push button. I tried using this code

```
void Notepad::on_pushButton_10_clicked(){
    Notepad::lineEdit -> setText("test");
}
```

but it does not work since `lineEdit` is not a member of Notepad. How do I reference `lineEdit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will look something like below :

```
void Notepad::on_pushButton_10_clicked(){
    ui->lineEdit->setText("test");
}
```

provided that you named the lineEdit Widget as the lineEdit.